# Why doesn't this HTML button work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a button within my code that should change the text 'hello' to 'Goodbye' but it doesn't work. What mistake have I made? My code is correctly indented in my coding program.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>chat</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style type="text/css">     
body {
    margin:0px;
}

#topBar {   
    background-color:#33ccff;
    width:100%;
    height:100px; 
    z-index:1;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

'#logo' is the ID of the div that holds the text that I want to change and '#loginbutton' is the button that I want to use.

```
#logo { 
    width:15%;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#login { 
    width:10%;
    height:60px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-radius:8px;
}
#loginbutton { --this is the button that I want to change the text with
    background-color: #lightgrey;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-family:Impact;
    line-height:60px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
#loginbutton:hover {
    background-color: black; 
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
</style>    
</head>

<body>
<div id="topBar">
```

Here is the button and the div with the text:

```
<div id="login">
<button id="loginbutton">LOG IN</button> <!--This is the button-->
</div>
<div id="logo">hello</div> <!--This is the text I am trying to change-->
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code that I was using:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
document.getElementById("loginbutton").onclick=function { 
    document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML="Goodbye";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see an error in the Javascript console? Did you even look there?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify () for the function which is missing in this case.

```
<script type="text/javscript">
document.getElementById("loginbutton").onclick=function() { 
document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML="Goodbye";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead, to add your click handler

```
<script type="text/javscript">
  document.getElementById("loginbutton").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML = "Goodbye";
  });
</script>
```

Update

Your existing code has a syntax error making it not work properly, where it is missing the parenthesis `()` after the word `function` and should look like this

```
document.getElementById("loginbutton").onclick=function() {
```

Comment: Whle this may be better style, it doesn't address the real problem in his code, which is a syntax error in the function definition.

Comment: @Barmar So right, should have addressed that when posted the first time ... updated and will in my upcoming answers

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<script type="text/javscript">
     document.getElementById("loginbutton").onclick = function() { 
     document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML = "Goodbye"; }
  //further code
</script>
```

Comment: You should explain what the problem was with the original, and what you changed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The spelling `text/javscript` is not correct. Correct the spelling and then add `()` after the function word.

See the corrected code snippet below:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 document.getElementById("loginbutton").onclick=function() { 
   document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML="Goodbye";
 }
</script>
```